# Finding the intersection of a ray and a plane programmatically?

Tags: c++, vector

I understand the math here: http://lousodrome.net/blog/light/2020/07/03/intersection-of-a-ray-and-a-plane/

This is my implementation of his equation:

```
    Vector3 difference = plane_point - ray_origin;
    double product_1 = difference.dot(plane_normal);
    double product_2 = ray_direction.dot(plane_normal);
    double distance_from_origin_to_plane = product_1 / product_2;
    Vector3 intersection = ray_origin - ray_direction * distance_from_origin_to_plane;
```

However, my implementation doesnt work unless I change the first line to:

```
Vector3 difference = ray_origin - plane_point;
```

But I cant figure out why that works. His math makes perfect sense. The working code makes no sense.

Can anyone explain whats going on?

Comment: Can you add the language in tag ?

Comment: Shouldn't ray_origin - plane_point; be in absolute function?

Comment: `intersection = ray_origin - ray_direction * distance_from_origin_to_plane;` doesn't sound correct assume the variable names are all correct. (it should be `+`)

Comment: Are you sure all the signs of all the axes are the same in your code as they are in the example? Or that you have all the signs in your code in the right place? I have the feeling something is off there

Answer (score 2):

apple apple answered it in the comments. The last line should have had a + not a -.

The working code that makes sense now is:

```
    Vector3 difference = plane_point - ray_origin;
    double product_1 = difference.dot(plane_normal);
    double product_2 = ray_direction.dot(plane_normal);
    double distance_from_origin_to_plane = product_1 / product_2;
    Vector3 intersection = ray_origin + ray_direction * distance_from_origin_to_plane;
```